# Can the Linux "at" command run in environments other than /bin/sh?

Tags: linux, bash, environment, at-job

I need a scheduler (for one time only actions) for a site I'm coding (in php), and I had two ideas:

1- Run a php script with crontab and verify against a database of scheduled actions and execute ones that are older than current time.

2- Schedule various tasks with the "at" command.

The second option seems much better and simpler, so that's what I'm trying to do. However, I haven't found a way to tell "at" to run a command using the PHP interpreter, and so far I've been creating a .sh script, which contains a single command, which is to run a file through the php interpreter. That is far from the optimal setting, and I wish I could just execute the php code directly through "at", something like:

```
at -e php -f /path/to/phpscript time
```

Is it possible? I haven't found anything about using environments other than bash in either the man or online.

Comment: You mean like "echo 'php -f /path/to/phpscript' | at time" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend `phpscript` with a `#!/usr/bin/php` (or wherever your php script is stored) and make `/path/to/phpscript` executable.  This is exactly what the `#!` syntax is for.

Just so it's clear, your `phpscript` would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

...your code goes here
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I can execute the script in the terminal using ./phpscript, but the at-command still seems to be using /bin/sh to execute.

Comment: You should explicitly set your `PATH` in  an `at` command file.

Answer (score 0):

The command you specify to `at` is executed by `/bin/sh`, but sh can invoke any command, executed directly or by any specified interpreter.

The following works on my Ubuntu 12.04 system with the bash shell:

```
$ cat hello.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    echo "Hello, PHP\n";
?>
$ echo "$PWD/hello.php > hello.php.out" | at 16:11
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 4 at Sat Aug 25 16:11:00 2012
$ date
Sat Aug 25 16:11:05 PDT 2012
$ cat hello.php.out
Hello, PHP
$
```

In some cases, you'll have to do some extra work to set environment variables correctly (it's not necessary for this simple case).  Quoting the man page:

> For both **at** and **batch**, commands are read from standard input or the
>   file specified with the **-f** option and executed. The working directory,
>   the environment (except for the variables **BASH_VERSINFO**, **DISPLAY**,
>   **EUID**, **GROUPS**, **SHELLOPTS**, **TERM**, **UID**, and **_**) and the umask are retained
>   from the time of invocation.
>
> As **at** is currently implemented as a setuid program, other environment
>   variables (e.g. **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** or **LD_PRELOAD**) are also not exported.
>   This may change in the future. As a workaround, set these variables
>   explicitly in your job.